# What material is used on the wing surface of this airplane?

Tags: aerospace-materials, amateur-built

This is one of the Redbull's 2015 Flugtag contestants; I was wondering what material is used on the wing surface of this airplane?

[image]

[video here](https://youtu.be/zXDPK8YRqRU?t=54).

Comment: seems normal plastic, why do you think is anything particular?

Comment: I was wondering if it is a rated material.

Comment: personally, I don't see why it would be, but I'll leave this to others that might have more specific info

Comment: Could be something along the lines of [clear monofilm like what they make sails out of](http://www.sailrite.com/Monofilm-5mil-54).

Comment: Looks like a biaxially stretched polyester terephthalate foil, like DuPont's Mylar.

Comment: I second Peter. There have already been a couple of Flugtag winners using carbon fiber and Mylar wings